# Length of a segment in rectangular parallelepiped

Tags: geometry, 3d, rectangles

I am stuck on a problem from a book. I have attached the picture of that question below.

[image]

My approach was to draw a line segment between `C` and `X` and another line segment between `C` and `Y`. This should make triangle `XCY`. Since `XCY` is a right triangle (assuming angle `XCY` is right), I can use pythagorean theorem to find the length of segment `XY`( answer to the question). Because the lengths of segments `CX` and `CY` can be found by using pythagorean theorem on triangle `CXD` and `CBY` respectively. The book's solution manual however gives a different answer.

I have explained the author's solution below, in case you require:

The author's approach is to make a segment `XL` where `XL` is parallel to `GH` and the point `L` lies on `CG`. Another segment `LM` which is parallel to `FG` where the point `M` lies on segment `FB`. Then create a triangle `XYL`. First, the author finds the length of segment `YL` using pythagorean on right triangle `LMY` ( point `M` is to the right of point `Y` on `FB`). Length of segment `XL` is known to be equal to `GH`. So finally the author, uses pythagorean theorem  on triangle `XYM` to find the answer (ie. the length of segment `XY`).

While I agree with the author's solution. I don't understand why my solution is wrong and gives a different answer than the author. Is it because my assumption of triangle `XCY` being a right triangle is wrong? Or something else?

Thanks

Comment: There is no reason to assume that angle XCY is a right angle.  If would be if $Y=B$ but as soon as Y moves towards F it becomes acute.  You should look at $\Delta x, \Delta y, and \Delta z$ between the 2 points.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce a $3$D reference system with origin in $A$.

Points have coordinates $Y=(4,3,0);\;X=(0,5,3)$

$$XY=\sqrt{(5-3)^2+(3+0)^2+(4+0)^2}=\sqrt{29}$$

---

[image]